# RxJS/Drag-and-drop: Drag event is triggered on mousedown in Chrome; why?

Tags: google-chrome, rxjs

I trying to achieve drag and drop functionality using RxJS. It works, almost, but the drag event gets triggered on mousedown, and I don't understand why.

Here's simplified version of the code, I'm listening on document just to make the example easier.

```
const down = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousedown');
const up = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
const move = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');

const drag = down.switchMap(() => move.takeUntil(up).take(1));
const dragging = drag.switchMap(() => move.takeUntil(up));
const drop = drag.switchMap(() => up.take(1));
```

`down`, `up`, `dragging` and `drop` works as expected, but `drag` gets triggered directly on mousedown, why?

JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/rafurudofe/1/edit?js,console,output

Edit:
Seems like it works as expected in IE, but not in Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't happen for me in Chrome. Are you sure there's no `move` fired?

Comment: `drag` get called directly on `down` even tho I haven't moved the mouse. Since drag is a `switchMap` of down and move it shouldn't get triggered until I've moved the  mouse. But it seems to be a Chrome bug, I've tested on OS X Chrome now and it works as expected, will report on RXJs Github page.